# Set default dropdownlist value based on radio button change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

If radio button has changed, I want to set the default value in dropdownlist and I want to show that value in dropdown.

1)  If I select radio Button as "No", I want to show "Fourth" in a dropdownlist. Else if it is "Yes" no need for any condition, it is as it is default.

2) I want to sent the "Fourth" text in a dropdownlist, once i will choose the radio button to "No".

Example,

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bjs3g/352/)

```js
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.mail_notifications = [{
      "key": "all",
      "value": "First"
    },
    {
      "key": "selected",
      "value": "Second"
    },
    {
      "key": "only_my_events",
      "value": "Third"
    },
    {
      "key": "only_assigned",
      "value": "Fourth"
    },
    {
      "key": "only_owner",
      "value": "Fifth"
    },
  ];
  $scope.mail_notification = 'all';

});
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="Yes" /> Yes <br />
  <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="No" /> No <br />
</form>


<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    {{message}} <br />

    <!--Options value is defualt 0, 1 ... and it's non change able -->
    <span>Default Otions:</span>
    <select ng-model="mail_notification" ng-options="c.key as c.value for c in mail_notifications"></select>
    <br />


  </div>
</div>
```

For me the dropdownlist as coming as empty. Can anyone please tell how can i do this?

Comment: What's the logic? What is the relation between `2` and `fourth` ? if select `1` then what?

Comment: If I select the radio button as that value, I want to show in a dropdown as "Fourth". Its just an sample values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign ng-click event for the radio button. But for that you have to write your form tag inside the controller.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bjs3g/363/)

```js
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.mail_notifications = [
        {
            "key": "all",
            "value": "First"
        },
        {
            "key": "selected",
            "value": "Second"
        },
        {
            "key": "only_my_events",
            "value": "Third"
        },
        {
            "key": "only_assigned",
            "value": "Fourth"
        },
        {
            "key": "only_owner",
            "value": "Fifth"
        },
    ];
    $scope.mail_notification = 'all';
   
   $scope.radioSelection=function(val){
        if(val==2){
           $scope.mail_notification='only_assigned';
        }
        if(val==1){
           $scope.mail_notification='all';
        }
   }
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
        {{message}} <br />
        <form id="myForm">
<input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="1" ng-click="radioSelection(1)"/> 1 <br />
<input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="2" ng-click="radioSelection(2)"/> 2 <br />
</form>
        <!--Options value is defualt 0, 1 ... and it's non change able -->
        <span>Default Otions:</span>
        <select ng-model="mail_notification" ng-options="c.key as c.value for c in mail_notifications"></select>
        <br />
        
                     
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I select 1, it should be default for the first time how it is.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I am expecting.

Comment: @sathishkumar i have made edit in the answer for default behavior.

Comment: @sathishkumar you can upvote the given answer if it is usefull.